# ReactJS: Passing state to child returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am setting the state in a parent component. Then when that state is set (with componentDidMount) I need to pass that to a child.

Currently, since it is returning undefined in the child component. I presume this is because state isn't set at the moment that the non-existent state is being passed. Making it undefined.

Tried putting `boolean` conditions in for state so it needs to be true before passing. `Booleans` in the child, in the parent, anywhere i thought it might make a difference and would prevent the component for looking for the prop I'm passing before it exists.

yearArr is being set here with the result of a function being executed as the component is mounted

```
    componentDidMount() {
        const yearArrSorted = dataSet && this.playFunction();

        this.setState({
            locationData: dataSet,
            yearArr: yearArrSorted
        });
        this._layerRendering();
        this._animate();
    }
```

here is the func:

```
playFunction = () => {
        //i know this is unreadable, but i wanted to see how simple i could go.
        return dataSet.map(i => {
            return Object.keys(Object.values(i)[2])
                .map(i => (i.startsWith(9) ? 19 + i : 20 + i))
                .sort();
        })[0];
    };
```

Here's state:

```
    this.state = {
            locationData: "",
            year: 95,
            elevationScale: elevationScale.min,
            yearArr: []
        };
```

Hjere is where state is being passed, with my terribly hacky approach to try to get the state only being passed once its set:

```
        <YearSelector
                    yearOnChange={this.yearOnChange}
                    year={this.state.year}
                    dataStateChange={this.dataStateChange}
                    dataSet={dataSet}
                    years={this.state.yeaArr.length > 0 && this.state.yeaArr}
                />
```

I expect to send state to the child component as a prop when it is set so that prop can be used to `.map` through the prop array and create a `<select>` DOM element with `<option>`

Can edit question as needed and code can be supplied.

Comment: Could you show more code please ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted the issues.

Tried this initially but it didn't work for whatever reason.

```
                    years={this.state.yearArr && this.state.yearArr}
```

Now it works, the method i tried at first, which is a status quo for react.